# How can I control cursor from software?

Tags: winapi

Basically, I want to develop a software that can move and control cursor without using mouse. But I have no idea what to start. I have a rough idea that call the windows API using C/C++. Can anybody give some tutorial or hint?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at the `SendInput` function as somewhere to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out where the mouse pointer is using [`GetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), move it using [`SetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and send mouse clicks using [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There's an example of using each of them from the linked pages.